# Keras fit_generator gives a dimension mismatch error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am working on MNIST dataset, in which `X_train = (42000,28,28,1)` is the training set. `y_train = (42000,10)` is the corresponding label set. Now I create an iterator from the image generator using Keras as follows;

```
iter=datagen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32)
```

which works fine.

Then I train the model using;

```
model.fit_generator(iter,steps_per_epoch=len(X_train)/32,epochs=1)
```

Here it gives the following error;

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 28, 28, 1)
```

I tried but failed to find the mistake. Also I searched here but there was no answer:

[expected dense_218_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (512, 28, 28, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850007/expected-dense-218-input-to-have-2-dimensions-but-got-array-with-shape-512-28)

BTW this is the summary of my model
[image: Model structure]

Please help me.

**Update:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
```

Comment: Dense layer can not process tensors with rank greater than 2. In that case it should be flattened first.

Comment: It actually contradicts with `iter=datagen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32)` as it requires `X_train` to be of rank 4. By flattening that property is violated. What are your inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape mismatch was the root-cause. Input shape was not matching with what `ImageDataGenetor` expects. Please check the following example with `mnist` data. I have used `Tensorflow 2.1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
x_train = tf.expand_dims(x_train,axis=-1)
x_test = tf.expand_dims(x_test,axis=-1)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2)

iter=datagen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28,1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#model.fit_generator(iter,steps_per_epoch=len(X_train)/32,epochs=1) # deprecated in TF2.1
model.fit_generator(iter,steps_per_epoch=len(iter),epochs=1)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/ImageGenerator_mnist.ipynb)

Comment: I was able to work with the model.fit() method earlier also but the problem is with the fit_generator(). Please help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the code above. Forgot to change last line model.fit_generator(iter,steps_per_epoch=len(iter),epochs=1)

Comment: Can you please update my code and share it so that I can tell you what you need to do. `ImageDataGenerator` and `fit_generator` looks for certain shape based on input data.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please find in the UPDATE section.so made it work but still, I have a doubt. Does `model.add(Flatten())` flatten the tensor prior to performing `Z=WX+b` that goes into the first hidden layer or does it flatten the output of the first hidden layer?